# Formatting non-filled cells in SSRS matrix

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a matrix in SQL Server Reporting Services that is, in general, doing what it needs to do.  However, I am trying to format the background color for the entire row depending on the value of a grouped by column.  My issue is that any of the cells that do not have a value do not get a background color.  So, my original data is:

[image: Raw Data]

This would then show up in my matrix as:

[image: Data in a matrix]

On each row, I then put a background format of:

```
=IIf(Fields!Highlight.Value="1", "Yellow", "White")
```

This unfortunately has an end result of:

[image: Formatted Matrix]

I am assuming that I could just return another row in my recordset of `Mark` with the `Y` condition and a `NULL` or empty string and a `Highlight` value of 1, but that would take some effort.  Is there a way to get the grouped by Highlight value for the entire row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just adding a Variable to my Row Group called Row_Highlight and just set it equal to Fields!Highlight.Value.  I could have set it to MAX(Fields!Highlight.Value) as well if the Highlight value varied within a user.  My format expression then became IIf(**Variables!Row_Highlight**.Value="1", "Yellow", "White").

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that either your `Highlight` column has the same value for each `User` value with the same value (i.e. `Mark` always has a `Highlight` value of `1`) or that if *any* of the rows have a `Highlight` value of `1`, that `User` should always be highlighted.

If either of those scenarios are the case, you should be able to change your row highlight expression to `=IIf(max(Fields!Highlight.Value, "YourRowGroupName") = 1, "Yellow", "White")` to have the entire grouped row affected.

Comment: Yes, each user always has the same Highlight value.  Your proposed solution still leaves cells without a background color.  I am assuming that your solution is doing the same thing as my original.  It is saying, give me all of the Mark rows with a Condition of Y and give me the Max(Highlight) value.  Since there are no rows, it doesn't evaluate to 1.

Comment: Where are you applying the expression?  You should be highlighting the row, not the individual table cells

Comment: The format expression still gets applied to the individual cells, even if you try to apply it to the row.  As far as I know, you can't apply a format at the row level per se.  Yes, you can select the row and type in a background color expression, but all that does is apply the expression to each of the cells in the row.

Comment: @BIBIBird Try adding in the row group context as per the expression in my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a little more complex expression to get what you need.  I would suggest using a comparison to the previous cell value to try to grab the correct coloring.

```
=IIf(Fields!Highlight.Value="1" 
OR (Previous(Fields!Highlight.Value)="1" AND IsNothing(Fields!Highlight.Value)), "Yellow", "White")
```

This may or may not work -- I'm not sure how your data is pivoted, but the idea is to check the previous cell for the highlight value, but only if the current cell does not have a highlight value.  This could be an issue if you have a value in the `X` column that is empty, but in that case, you could try to add a similar comparison based on the user.

```
...AND Previous(Fields!User.Value) = Fields!User.Value
```

Anyways, you get the idea, I'm sure you can adapt this to fit your needs.